# How to write a callback function for asynchronous calls from helper method to componentDidMount using React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have a helper js file and in that have a asynchronous calls method, in my component am importing the helper js file and in componentDidMount, am making the call.

Before ajax completion, the value is getting returned as undefined. Is there a way to write a callback function, on success it should come to my componentDidMount method.

This is what I tried:

helper.js

```
export const asynchronous = data => {
   axios.get(url).then(res => {
     return res;
   });
}
```

component.js

```
import {asynchronous} from 'helper';

componentDidMount(){
  const newResp = asynchronous(this.props.data);
  console.log(newResp); // returned before api success/failure, should be returned after api request
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `async-await`

```
async componentDidMount(){
  const newResp = await asynchronous(this.props.data);
  console.log(newResp); // returned before api success/failure, should be returned after api request
}
```

And your `asynchronous` code. You're missing a `return` statement.

```
export const asynchronous = data => {
   return axios.get(url).then(res => {
     return res;
   });
}
```

An Example : [Async Await with React Lifecycle methods](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/async-await-with-react-lifecycle-methods-802e7760d802)

Comment: after adding async and await the value is still returning as undefined and then it is going inside success block.

Comment: I edited the answer. You are missing a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add async to componentDidMount then await the response.

```
// helper.js
async function getData(url) {
   const response = await axios.get(url);
   console.log(response);

   return response;
}

export default getData;
```

In your component:

```
import { getData } from './helper.js'; // <-- Not 'helper' which looks in node modules
...
componentDidMount = async () => {
  const newResp = await asynchronous(this.props.data);

  console.log(newResp);
}
...
```

More than that, you will want to do something with that response.

```
...
componentDidMount = async () => {
  const newResp = await asynchronous(this.props.data);

  this.setState({ data: newResp })
}
...
```

Comment: after adding async and await the value is still returning as undefined and then it is going inside success block.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the intial axios promise and then use its `then`,

```
export const asynchronous = data => {
   return axios.get(url);
}
```

And use it in your componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount(){
  const newResp = asynchronous(this.props.data).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
   });
}
```